# Android BtGatt blocks scan because no slots left for scan filter history

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

- Question is

1. Can i reset BTGatt.ScanFilterHistory through code?
2. There is any way to solve this problem?

---

- Description is

My Android application uses the Bluetooth to communicate with an external BLE module device. But we facing the problem when scanning with BluetoothLeScanner.

When my app try to scan bluetooth, it doesn't work with message `D BtGatt.ScanFilterHistory Blocked: 86 filters of com.htbeyond.bybeyond(7) becuz only 26 slots left`. Any one has this problem?

Comment: I get the same crap from Samsung OS 11. I have not seen that before. In my case its Blocked: 19 filters of com.lni.health.at.home(11) becuz only 18 slots left